# Remove multiple MD menu containers

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I have an AngularJS 1.6/Typescript project in which I have a Material Design menu element. Inside the menu element I have a select with multiple options.

If I click open the menu and then click on the select and then outside the select element only the menu container is removed. Since the md-backdrop element for the menu has a higher z-index than the md-backdrop for the select element.

I would like to be able to remove both the menu and the select container with a single click.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ELOvJd

```
<md-menu>
    <md-button aria-label="Open phone interactions menu" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$mdMenu.open();">
      qq
    </md-button>
    <md-menu-content width="4">
      <md-menu-item>
        <md-button>
            yy
        </md-button>
      </md-menu-item>
      <md-menu-item>
        <md-button>
            zz
          </md-button>
      </md-menu-item>
      <md-menu-divider></md-menu-divider>
      <md-menu-item>
        <md-button>
          xx
        </md-button>
      </md-menu-item>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Status</label>
        <md-select ng-model="ctrl.userState">
          <md-option><em>None</em></md-option>
          <md-option>
            Something
          </md-option>
          <md-option>
            Something
          </md-option>
          <md-option>
            Something
          </md-option>
          <md-option>
            Something
          </md-option>
        </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
    </md-menu-content>
  </md-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it required for you to use a select?  Why not utilize a second menu?

Example: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmXOOj

```
<div class="md-menu-demo menudemoBasicUsage" ng-controller="BasicDemoCtrl as ctrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">

  <md-menu>
    <md-button aria-label="Open phone interactions menu" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$mdMenu.open();">
      qq
    </md-button>
    <md-menu-content width="4">
      <md-menu-item>
        <md-button>
            yy
        </md-button>
      </md-menu-item>
      <md-menu-item>
        <md-button>
            zz
          </md-button>
      </md-menu-item>
      <md-menu-item>
        <md-button>
          xx
        </md-button>
      </md-menu-item layout="row">
            <md-menu>
    <md-button aria-label="Open interactions menu" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$mdMenu.open();">
      >>
              </md-button>
              <md-menu-content width="4">
                          <md-menu-item>
        <md-button>
            aa
        </md-button>
      </md-menu-item>
      <md-menu-item>
        <md-button>
            bb
          </md-button>
      </md-menu-item>
      <md-menu-item>
        <md-button>
          cc
        </md-button>
      </md-menu-item>
                </md-menu-content>
              </md-menu>

    </md-menu-content>
  </md-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've played around a bit and we can listen to the mdMenuClose emitter. And from that point we call the ``$mdSelect.hide()` function to hide the select box when the mdMenu is closed.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxXbrX

```
$scope.$on('$mdMenuClose', function (event) {
    $mdSelect.hide();
});
```